# Efficiently creating a checkerboard pattern of 0s and 255s

Tags: python, numpy

I had wrote a function to generate a example numpy array by for loop. But it is too slow for larger dimension.

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.zeros((5, 5))

def func(im):
    im = im.copy()
    h,w = im.shape
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                im[i, j] = 255
    return im
print(func(mat))
#    array([[ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.],
#        [   0.,  255.,    0., ...,    0.,  255.,    0.],
#        [ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.],
#        ..., 
#        [ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.],
#        [   0.,  255.,    0., ...,    0.,  255.,    0.],
#        [ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will start with a zero intialized array. So, that will be : `np.zeros((heigh, width))`. Next up, we would have few approaches to fill it with such a pattern of alternating `255s`.

**Approach #1 :** Use *open* range arrays with [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) to simulate those iterators and directly translate the comparisons in a vectorized manner leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
I,J = np.ogrid[:h,:w]
im[(I+J)%2==0] = 255
```

**Approach #2 :** Taking a closer look, it seem you are setting every other element in each row to `255`, starting from the first element for first row and second element for the second row and back to first for the third row and so on. Thus, we can use [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) as well and should be pretty efficient -

```
im[::2,::2] = 255
im[1::2,1::2] = 255
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def func(im):
    h,w = im.shape
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                im[i, j] = 255
    return im

def app1(im):
    h,w = im.shape    
    I,J = np.ogrid[:h,:w]
    im[(I+J)%2==0] = 255
    return im

def app2(im):
    im[::2,::2] = 255
    im[1::2,1::2] = 255
    return im
```

Verify -

```
In [74]: im = np.random.randint(0,255,(1000,1000))

In [75]: im1 = im.copy()
    ...: im2 = im.copy()
    ...: im3 = im.copy()
    ...: 

In [76]: func(im1)
    ...: app1(im2)
    ...: app2(im3)
    ...: 
Out[76]: 
array([[255, 133, 255, ...,  14, 255,  41],
       [235, 255, 191, ..., 255,  40, 255],
       [255, 151, 255, ...,  51, 255,  18],
       ..., 
       [ 50, 255, 177, ..., 255, 193, 255],
       [255, 245, 255, ..., 114, 255,  27],
       [223, 255, 148, ..., 255, 200, 255]])

In [77]: print np.allclose(im1,im2)
    ...: print np.allclose(im1,im3)
    ...: 
True
True
```

Timings -

```
In [78]: %timeit func(im)
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit app1(im)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit app2(im)
1000 loops, best of 3: 415 µs per loop

In [82]: 106/0.415 # Speedup with approach #2 over original one
Out[82]: 255.42168674698797
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fancy indexing properties of numpy arrays.

An example that does exactly what you need is:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((10, 10))
a = np.arange(0, 10, 2)
b = np.arange(1, 10, 2)
arr[a[:, None], a[None, :]] = 255
arr[b[:, None], b[None, :]] = 255

print(arr)
array([[ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,    0.,  255.,    0.],
       [   0.,  255.,    0., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.],
       [ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,    0.,  255.,    0.],
       ..., 
       [   0.,  255.,    0., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.],
       [ 255.,    0.,  255., ...,    0.,  255.,    0.],
       [   0.,  255.,    0., ...,  255.,    0.,  255.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeating patterns such as yours.

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
x = np.tile(np.array([[0,255],[255,0]]),(n,n))
```